# Relating list to each

Tags: python, list, random

Just a problem I'm having and can't seem to figure out.

I have two tables: table1 and table2:

```
table1=[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and

```
table2=[0 for i in range (21)]
```

I want to run:

```
import random
for d1 in range(21):
    table2[d1] = random.expovariate(gamma_val)
```

But if value in `table1 = 1`, that position in `table2` should run `random.expovariate(x)`,
and if not 1 run `random.expovariate(y)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly would you not just:

```
import random
for d1 in range(21):
    if table1[d1]: #1 evaluates to true in python
       table2[d1] = random.expovariate(x)
    else:
       table2[d1] = random.expovariate(y)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
table2 = []
for d1 in table1:
    value = x if d1 == 1 else y
    table2.append(random.expovariate(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be:

```
import random
options = [y, x]
for d1 in range(21):
    table2[d1] = random.expovariate(options[table1[d1]])
```

I'm using the values `(0` or `1`) as indexes of the `options` list.

Answer (score 1):

If you want table2 to be the same size as table1, you can (and should) use something like this:

```
table2 = [random.expovariate(x if d1 else y) for d1 in table1]
```